# Calling request localhost always returns status code 200

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, localhost, http-status-code-200

This is my very first question here. I am working on a Spring Boot application. Today I encountered a weird problem.

When I run my app and call `POST http://localhost:8080/report` for example, I should get `pdf` in response or some type of error code if something went wrong, but instead I get status **200** OK without a body.

When I tried to call a nonexistent service same thing happened. I put a breakpoint at the very first line of the implementation of this service but it never got there.

I tried to reinstall Java, and IntelliJ, updated windows, and disabled the firewall. This morning it worked just fine. I don't really understand what happened and I'm here to ask you what possibly could cause this.

It happened shortly after adding a certificate to Keystore, but I have done this so many times and this never happened before. Sorry for not being more specific, but I don't really know where to be specific because it suddenly stopped working.

Since I am a windows user, I ran `netstat -ano -p tcp |find "8080"`, to check if the port is free. When the app is running I get

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       12832
```

when I stop the application, I do not get any output. Also tried changing the port to something else, but did not help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the specific code I suspect. All of my other projects behave the same way.

Comment: this is a common problem if you define your own filter but forget to call the filterChain - `filterChain.doFilter(request, response);` without which you keep getting `200` without body

Answer (score 1):

Check what's running on port 8080 using `sudo lsof -i :8080`.

It's likely you already have another service there.

`localhost` can point to both IPv4 and IPv6 interfaces, so multiple apps can technically bind on the same port on `localhost`.

The solution would be to either [change your Spring Boot app port](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-change-port) or kill the conflicting app / change its port.

Java apps can be also forced to bind only to IPv4 interface using `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` in the VM Options.

Comment: i just tried all u mentioned. Sadly, problem still persists. But thanks for answering.

Comment: Post `sudo lsof -i :8080` output in your question.

Comment: question updated

Comment: Do you have any third-party security or proxy software that can intercept and handle HTTP requests on this system? Can you share any sample project and provide the exact steps to trigger this problem so that others can try it on their systems and report if they get the same results? This will help to isolate the issue.

Comment: Sorry for the very late answer; I totally forgot about this question. A colleague of mine commented some parts of the code in shared module and pushed it to the master branch.